# Eliminar elemento de un arreglo de clases C#(.net)

Tags: c#, .net

estuve buscando en internet para ver si encontraba algo pero no logre encontrar nada,y lamentablemente mis conocimientos aún son bajos,por lo cual vine aquí nuevamente.

Les cuento,tengo una biblioteca de clases con una clase llamada "profesor" con sus respectivas variables,y un arreglo de clases llamado "Duos" donde tengo un array de tipo profesor con sus respectivos metodos.Tengo un metodo para agregar "profesor" al arreglo y tambien buscar un "profesor" por el atributo rut.

metodo agregar:

```
public string AgregarProfesor(Profesor p)
{
     if (buscar(p.Rut) == -1)
     {
          Array.Resize(ref _profesor, Profesor.Length + 1);
          _profesor[Profesor.Length - 1] = p;
          return "\n\nSe agregó nuevo profesor.";
     }
     return "\nEl Profesor ya existe, No se agregó.";
}
```

metodo buscar:

```
public int buscar(string rut)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < _profesor.Length; i++)
     {
           if (Profesor[i].Rut == rut)
               return i;
            }
            return -1;
      }
}
```

Necesito crear un metodo el cual me permita usar el metodo buscar para buscar un profesor y eliminarlo del arreglo,pero he intentado varias cosas y buscado en internet y lo unico que encuentro tiene que ver con una lista de arreglos,toda ayuda es bienvenida,muchas gracias.

Comment: Forzosamente tienes que usar un arreglo? porque seria mejor que usar una lista

Comment: así es amigo, según el curso de mi institución, estamos viendo objetos y arreglos de clases, pero no arraylist :/, y posiblemente en el examen que tendré pronto, seguramente saldrá el tema de eliminar un elemento del arreglo

Answer (score 1):

Como te han comentado el Array no es el objeto más apropiado para mantener una colección de elementos en la que quieres añadir o eliminar elementos en cualquier posición.

El coste de redimensionar el Array y reordenar sus elementos es muy grande y tienes otros tipos que son más apropiados para realizar este tipo de operaciones.

Si, como explicas, por motivos académicos debe ser un Array creo que la mejor opción para eliminar un elemento, por coste y claridad de código, es generar un nuevo Array con los elementos restantes.

Mira este ejemplo:

```
var arrNumbers = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
// Eliminar el 4:
arrNumbers = arrNumbers.Where(i => i != 4).ToArray();
// arrNumbers ->  int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 }
```

Para eliminar el número 4 del Array arrNumbers lo que estoy haciendo es crear un nuevo Array con todos los elementos que no son el número 4 y asignárselo a la variable arrNumbers.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que sería algo como

```
public void EliminarProfesor(Profesor p) { 
    //si es diferente de -1 es por que si existe entonces si podes eliminar 
    if(buscar(p.Rut)!=-1) { 
        int index = buscar(p.Rut); 
        //guardo el index en el que se encuentra el profe 
        _profesor.removeAt(index); //elimino el profesor en esa posicion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no hay un método para eliminar elementos de un Array en C# o .Net, no al menos que haya encontrado. En gral un Array se utiliza para una determinada cantidad de elementos, que en todo caso se puede agrandar, pero no hacerla más chica. Para más información sobre arreglos puedes ver este tutorial [Tutorial Arreglos en MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx).

Si querés eliminar elementos deberías utilizar ArrayList o List. Los ArrayList y List tienen los métodos RemoveAt() que elimina el elemento en la posición indicada o Remove() que elimina el primer elemento que coincida con el string pasado.

Por métodos para eliminar en ArrayList puedes ver este enlace [ArrayList Remove Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.remove(v=vs.110).aspx).